# How to instantiate subclass from within a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, superclass

What's wrong with the following code and how do I fix it? My objective is to work with a superclass in my `main` method. This superclass object is supposed to itself create (in its internal state) instances of its subclass. 
The purpose of this is because the subclass only needs the state of the superclass to work with, and because all operations the subclass needs to do are only important as far as the superclass is concerned.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 testSuperclass = new Test2("success #1");
    }   
}

class Test2 {
    public Test2(String printComment) {
        System.out.println(printComment);
        Test3 testSubclass = new Test3("success #2");
    }
}

class Test3 extends Test2 {
    public Test3(String printComment2) {
        System.out.println(printComment2);
    }
}
```

The `Test3` constructor is generating the error `Implicit super constructor Test2() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing a constructor has to do is call a constructor for the superclass.

Often, you don't see that, because the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the non-arguments constructor (`super()`) if you don't specify another one. But in your case, there is no non-argument constructor in Test2 (because you created another one that needs a String).

```
public Test3(String printComment2) {
    super(printComment2);
    System.out.println(printComment2);
}
```

Comment: So if I was to put in the appropriate constructor such that `super()` could be called, this call to `super()` does basically nothing and would allow me to get the functionality that I specified in my post?

Comment: If you add a no-arg constructor to Test2, it will be called by the compiler automatically. Whether that does something or not is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Thilo's answer, when you don't explicitly define a super(a call to the parent's constructor) an implicit call is made as simply "super()". So you are essentially allowing a call to Test2's constructor but without passing a string resulting in an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do one of the following :

1. If you just want to make your code work without any additional printing or creating objects, create a no-arg constructor :

   ```
   class Test2 {
       public Test2(){
       }
       public Test2(String printComment) {
           System.out.println(printComment);
           Test3 testSubclass = new Test3("success #2");
       }
   }

   class Test3 extends Test2 {
       public Test3(String printComment2) {
           System.out.println(printComment2);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or the other way was as Thio mentioned :

   ```
   public Test3(String printComment2) {
     super(printComment2);
     System.out.println(printComment2);
   }
   ```